# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Pro Webmasters' [fourth moderator election](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Dan]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view the results online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5633571431645184/0).

Comment: Oh, I was kind of looking forward to voting in a moderator election but just found this page. Out of future interest, how would I know next time when it's taking place and how to vote?

Comment: @AndrewLott You'll see a notice of it in the community bulletin to the right of the page, as well as several election related meta posts. Pretty much anything important ends up in the community bulletin - but it's also worth checking meta from time to time.

Comment: Oh, I never noticed that section! I'll keep an eye on it now that I know what it is.

Answer (score 6):

Now, we have a new good moderator. Congratulations dan, you deserve it!

Comment: Many thanks for that Zistoloen, and for your amazing contributions to the site too!

Answer (score 5):

Hearty congratulations Dan. I'm very happy to see you as a new moderator :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, and for stepping up too - hope to see more contributions from you on the site!

Comment: Thanks dan. I will improve myself and will contribute much better than before.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations for your new role. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule ^(dan)$ /Well-done-$1! [R=301,L]
```

Comment: LOL, thanks - that works! :-)

Comment: Great geek joke :-).